# Using tinymce in a typescript project

Tags: typescript, tinymce

How would I go about using tinymce in a typescript project?  Below is what I have tried so far:

in my project directory:

```
npm install tinymce
```

tghis installs tinymce version 5.9.2 into the node_modules folder in my typescript project.

an in my Main.ts file:

```
import tinymce from '../node_modules/tinymce/tinymce';

export class Main{

    constructor() {
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea'
        });
    }
}


let main = new Main();
```

and in my index.html I have the textarea html tag.

When I run the above, it seems like tinymce is doing something, but it simply adds visibility:hidden to the textarea and assigns an id of "mce_0", other than than the editor does not load and the textarea remains a normal textarea.

Have I overlook something?

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE relies on CSS and Javascript files that are normally loaded during the `init` call.

When you include TinyMCE using a script tag then TinyMCE can retrieve those CSS files relative to the URL of the script, however if you choose to bundle TinyMCE then the script URL does not have any other TinyMCE assets relative to it so there is no way for the additional CSS and Javascript files to be added to the page unless you do it manually yourself.

If possible I recommend avoiding bundling and instead linking to a folder containing TinyMCE and its assets on your webserver. This will make it easier to add new plugins to TinyMCE and to support the premium plugins which sometimes have more complex loading patterns. If you want you can still use npm to get TinyMCE by setting up a build script that copies the folder from the `node_modules` into your `public` directory.

If you still decide that you want to bundle TinyMCE then I recommend looking at the bundling documentation at:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/introduction_to_bundling_tinymce/

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that if I do not bundle then I cannot use tinymce in my typescript project?  The main goal is here is to use tinymce in a typescript project

Comment: You can still use TinyMCE in a typescript project without bundling, it's just that you'll want to declare the `tinymce` variable instead of import it. For example: `declare const tinymce: TinyMCE;` where `TinyMCE` is imported via `import { TinyMCE } from 'tinymce';`. You'll see this same approach is done in the official TinyMCE repo as well: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/develop/modules/tinymce/src/core/demo/ts/demo/FullDemo.ts#L7